# Multiple fdopen() on a same filedescriptor fd?

Tags: c, io

I am trying to understand the standard I/O. I met a problem of calling fdopen().

What's the behavior if I call fdopen() on the same file descriptor as follows? Why do I get an ouput of '\377' (-1) ?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{

  int fd1, fd2;
  char c;

  FILE *fp1, *fp2;

  fd1 = open("foo.txt", O_RDONLY, 0);
  fp1 = fdopen(fd1, "r");
  fp2 = fdopen(fd1, "r");

  if (fp2 == NULL)
    printf("NULL\n");

  if (errno)
    printf("ERROR\n");

  c = fgetc(fp1);
  c = fgetc(fp2);

  printf("c = %c\n", c);


  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your stdio buffer size is 4K. The first `fgetc` reads 4K into the buffer and returns the first byte. The fd is now advanced 4K into the file. The second `fgetc` reads from there. Your file is smaller than the buffer size, so you're at EOF. You print the EOF with `%c` and get a funny character.

Multiple `fdopen` on a single `fd` gets a vote of **don't try it; it will hurt** from me. With an exception for creating `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` from a single tty descriptor if you're writing `getty`.

Comment: Thanks! That means fgetc caches in first, that's why EOS happens.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems:

1. `char` is not the right type for storing the return value of `fgetc`. Use `int`.
2. You're accessing the same open file description via two different handles without performing the steps necessary to switch between them legally. This invokes undefined behavior.
3. Checking `errno` and inferring from it that there was an error is not valid. If you already know there was an error, `errno` tells you which one. It does not tell you whether or not an error occurred, and in case one did not, any nonzero value may have been written to `errno`.
4. We don't know your file contents so we can't know what you expect to be read.